# Convert to miladi date to shamsi return zero for month and day

Tags: c#, .net

I use below code but that **`_newDate=139949`** but I want to value of variable `_newDate` equal **13990409**.
How to I get this value **13990409** please help me :)

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;
PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
string _newDate = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", pc.GetYear(newDate), pc.GetMonth(newDate), pc.GetDayOfMonth(newDate));
```

Comment: You could do `"{0}{1:00}{2:00}"` to get the leading zeros.  But I'd imagine there's a way to do a `yyyyMMdd` format with the calendar and date.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @juharr